# How to use Node.JS function separately?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've recently started learning JS and the answer to my question will probably be pretty easy :)

I need to:

1. Get a "challenge" for a funcaptcha on the first computer
2. Save the challenge to a text document
3. Transfer the text document to another computer (manually)
4. Apply `getImage()` to the challenge (from the first computer) to get a picture for that challenge, on the second computer.

Here is the code for step 1 and 2. It works ok.

```
const fun = require("funcaptcha");
const fs = require('fs');

const token = await fun.getToken({
    pkey: "476068BF-9607-4799-B53D-966BE98E2B81", // The public key
    site: "https://roblox-api.arkoselabs.com", // The site which contains the funcaptcha
}).then(async token => {
    let session = new fun.Session(token);
    let challenge = await session.getChallenge();

    image = challenge.getImage() //Just to ensure it's working okay. 

    filePath = //Path to the text file
    fs.writeFile(filePath, challenge)

});
```

Now, I transfer the text file to another computer and try using the following code:

```
const fun = require("funcaptcha");
const fs = require('fs');

const filePath = //path to file;

fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  } else {
    const challenge = data;
    console.log('Success:', challenge);
  }
});

image = await challenge.getImage()
```

This code causes the error

> TypeError: challenge.getImage is not a function

Why can't `getImage()` be applied to a challenge anymore? It worked great in my first code snippet.

How can this be fixed?

Thanks :)

P.S here is an example of "challenge" - https://pastebin.com/J9nGE1cX

Link to "funcaptcha" npm - https://www.npmjs.com/package/funcaptcha

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, `TypeError: challenge.getImage` is not a function, is because `challenge` on the second computer is just a string (the file's content), not an object with a `getImage` method.

You need to create a new `Session` object on the second computer, and then get a new `challenge` object from that session.

```
const fun = require("funcaptcha");
const fs = require('fs');

const filePath = //path to file;

fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  } else {
    const token = data;
    console.log('Success:', token);
    let session = new fun.Session(token);
    let challenge = await session.getChallenge();
    const image = await challenge.getImage();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have a question:

As far as I understand, with your solution, I will get a new challenge, and getImage() will be applied to the new challenge. Is that correct?

I need to get the image for the challenge from the first computer. That's why I'm saving it.

Comment: The funcaptcha library and its objects (like Session and the object returned by getChallenge) are not designed to be serialized to a file and then deserialized back into objects. The methods of these objects (like getImage) depend on the internal state of these objects, which is lost when you serialize them to a text file.

Answer (score -2):

The issue you're facing is due to a scoping problem. In your first code snippet, the challenge variable is declared within the then callback function, making it accessible within that function. However, in the second code snippet, challenge is declared within the fs.readFile callback function, making it inaccessible outside of that function.

To fix this, you need to ensure that the challenge variable is accessible in the scope where you want to use it. You can declare it in a higher scope, such as at the beginning of your script, so that it can be accessed both within and outside the fs.readFile callback. Here's a modified version of your second code snippet to illustrate this:

```
const fun = require("funcaptcha");
const fs = require('fs');

const filePath = // path to file;
let challenge; // Declare challenge in a higher scope

fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  } else {
    challenge = data; // Assign the value of challenge from the file
    console.log('Success:', challenge);

    // Now you can use challenge outside this callback
    const image = await challenge.getImage();
    // Use the 'image' variable as needed
  }
});
```

By declaring challenge at a higher scope, you can assign its value inside the fs.readFile callback and then use it elsewhere in your script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy